# Azure Data Factory foreach activity step size support

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that contains a list of IDs as input and I need to iterate through these IDs and call a REST API using batches of 10 IDs per time (these IDs will be passed as a parameter into JSON request).

1) Is there any approach using forEach activity in Data Factory passing the step size?

2) Do you have any other suggestions of how to accomplish this?

I have tried using "forEach" loop and also thinking in a way to use "setVariable" and "appendVariable" activities to store the current index during the loop, but also couldn't find a way to get the current index during the "forEach".

Comment: I have exactly that issue, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `LookupActivity`. With that you can get information from database, files or whatever and them pass it to a `ForEach` Loop.

Consider I have the following information in my txt file:

```
name|age
orochiBrabo|25
NarutoBoy|98
```

You can recover it using `LookupActivity` which I will call `MyLookUp` and then connect it box with a `ForEach` Box.

In `ForEach` Activity setting tab you write `@activity('MyLookUp').output.value` and now you can iterate over all rows in the file. Inside your ForEach you can refer results like `item().age` , `item().name` or `item().myColumnName`.

Comment: I have exactly this structure right now. However, I need to iterate over the content getting 10 rows/items at time (with step size=10), similar to programming languages iteration:

for(i=0; i<1000; i+=10){
   call REST API for list[i, i+10]
}

Do you have any recommendation in this case? Please contact me if you could help go further (https://diegoca80.github.io/).

Comment: If you want process 10 rows at same time you should deselect sequential option and set Batch Count to 10 in Foreach setting Tab.

And then you do all your processing stuffs inside foreach.

Comment: I guess setting the batch count to 10 will process 10 items in parallel in each time.

I need to process groups of 10 items each time - calling a API with these 10 items for each call.